# How to insert letter "N" and have followed by 4 digits. The 4 digits is entered by the user in to the text box

Tags: vb.net, winforms

> NOTE: I tried using concat() method, join method and even tried to
>   insert just text(which turned out editable) but none of them worked as
>   I wanted. I was thinking if substring method will work but I only have
>   basic idea of how substring works. I want the letter "N" to be
>   inserted into the text box when form loads and when the user enters
>   4digits(OrderNo2.text) which should be joined so that it can be saved
>   together when I clicked on save button.
>
> Please help guys. Thanks

```
Private Sub btnAddOrder_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e
  As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddOrder.Click



isNewRow = True
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dsOrders.Tables("Orders").NewRow

        Try
            If txtOrderNo2.Text.Length = 5 Then
                newRow.Item("OrderNo") = txtOrderNo2.Text
                If cbo_Product.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                    newRow.Item("Product") = cbo_Product.Text
                    newRow.Item("Price") = txtPrice2.Text
                    If txtQuantity.Text <> "" Then
                        newRow.Item("Quantity") = txtQuantity.Text
                        newRow.Item("CustomerNo") = txtCustomerNo2.Text
                        dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Rows.Add(newRow)
                        'determine row index of new row
                        rowIndex = dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Rows.Count - 1
                        'save changes back to the database
                        daOrders.Update(dsOrders, "Orders")

                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the quantity", "Missing Quantity", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please choose the product", "Missing Price", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Order Number must be 5 digits long!", "Missing Order Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: If the N is in the TextBox then it will be editible. I suggest you have the "N" in a label left of the TextBox then validate the text as a 4 digit number and perform the concatenation later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't do that way because it is the order number and I'm checking the length of string in the text box and saving it back to the database

Comment: you can, you could do 'newRow.Item("OrderNo") = String.Format("N{0}", txtOrderNo2.Text)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fkc1cz6.aspx) instead of a regular `TextBox`.  You can then set the [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property to `"N0000"`, which will only allow the user to enter 4 digits following the `'N'`, and will not let the user edit the `'N'`.  The `Text` property will give you the displayed text, including the `'N'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try just allowing only digits in the textbox with a max lenght of 4.
Then if the user clicks on the submit button just get the value of the input and place the N infront of it.
You will always have a length of 4 + your character("N") is 5.

That way you should be able to fix it.

You can also try using a regex. to see if it contains the N and numbers from 0-9.
only if it starts with the character N followed by 4 numberic characters it will be a valid input.

This would be your regex then.

^(N?[0-9]{4})$

Hope this can be of any use to you